# Formula Field Cannot be summarized in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Crystal report page footer formula field not summarized and not display in insert summary.

I have created a Report to generate Sales details, below picture

[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vafRT.jpg)

above report I need to display Actual Profit field on each invoice row and finally summarized and get sum of Actual Profit on Page footer.

1. I have created Actual Profit formula field, blow picture its working fine.

[created formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkHbb.png)

Problem is when i right click report footer section and insert a summary to get Sum of each invoice "Actual Profit" Not viewing formula field "Actual Profit" and also I tried to create a formula to get Total summary of (Sum of) Actual Profit field i'm getting error "This field cannot be summarized." below picture

[summarized error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHxf4.jpg)

How can I add summary of Total "Actual Profit" on page footer?

Answer (score 0):

An easy option would be to make a hidden Running Total of the Net Profit per Invoice and show this at the page footer. [image: Running Total]